# Http 'multipart/form-data' vs raw binary 'image/jpeg' for image uploading?

Tags: image, http, multipart, uploading

When I look for the ways to upload image to the server more often I find tutorials where Multipart approach is described. I am curious why multipart is better than simple raw binary uploading?

Answer (score 0):

After a while I have faced significant problem related to sending data as headers except of parameters. OkHttp doesn't allow non-ASCII characters in headers by default. It results in crash, which can be fixed by adding header in unsafe way:

```
private fun createHeaders(dataHeader: FileUploadDataHeader): Headers =
    Headers.Builder()
            .add(UPLOAD_HEADER_COMMAND, UPLOAD_HEADER_COMMAND_VALUE)
            .add(HEADER_TOKEN_NAME, userSettings.sessionUser.uuid)
            .addUnsafeNonAscii(UPLOAD_HEADER_DATA, dataHeader.toString())
            .build()
```

It would be better to use Multipart request, or at least encode non-ASCII value, and later decode it on the server. But this requeires collaboration with server-side developers, which is not always possible.